# Posición columnas en un dataframe python

Tags: python, dataframe

Estoy tratando de guardar en variables la enumeración de las páginas web cargadas en el código.

El código del cual tomo la información es el siguiente:

```
true_k = 8 # Número final de clúster
model = KMeans(n_clusters=true_k, init='k-means++',max_iter=1000, n_init=8, random_state=9731)
model.fit(data_fin)
labels = model.labels_
table = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(urls,labels)),columns=['title','cluster'])
print(table.sort_values(by=['cluster']))
```

Y del cual obtengo la siguiente tabla: [tabla clustering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/63lDL.png)

Sin embargo, cuando intento llamar solo la primera columna de la variable "table", me retorna tanto el número como el link de acceso. (por ejemplo me aparece: [resultado](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OwPCg.png)) por lo tanto la variable no es de tipo "int".

lo que busco es guardar en una variable lo que señalo en rojo a continuación:

[Resultado esperado](https://i.stack.imgur.com/06ed5.png)

Agradecería si pueden orientarme con esto. Muchas gracias!

Comment: Hola creo que lo que estas buscando son los `indices` en los `dataframes`. aqui puedes obtener mas informacion
https://www.delftstack.com/es/howto/python-pandas/set-column-as-index-pandas/ Espero ayudar.

Comment: Yo no acabo de entender lo que necesitas. ¿Podrías editar la pregunta y añadir un ejemplo del resultado que querrías obtener?

Comment: Listo, ajustado. Quedo atenta si mejoré la redacción de mi inquietud, mcuhas gracias

Comment: Ah, entiendo. Parece que lo que quieres es simplemente el índice del dataframe. Entonces sería `table.sort_values(by=['cluster']).index` o si quieres que el resutado sea una lista estándar python pon `list()` alrededor de esa expresión.

Comment: Muchas gracias, esto me sirvió :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Prueba con:

```
table.index
```

o con:

```
list(table.index)
```

Comment: Hola Diego, aunque tu respuesta puede ayudar como guía para resolver el problema de la pregunta, ha sido marcada como de baja calidad por la comunidad debido a su extensión y contenido. Las publicaciones que son básicamente código sin una explicación de lo que hacen o cómo solucionan el problema no suelen ser de ayuda a otros usuarios. Por favor, edita tu respuesta para añadir más detalles y una descripción de lo que hace cada opción. Lee [answer] para más información.